# "Error: attempt to apply non-function" shown when trying to describe data

Tags: r, data-manipulation

For one of my uni reports I have to analyse some data in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) and I have gotten to the descriptive part but when I enter the following code I get a notice saying:

> Error:attempt to apply non-function

I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
age_desc <- data %>%
  mutate(AGE_YEARS = all(duplicated(AGE_YEARS)[-1L])(AGE_YEARS)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(AGE_YEARS, na.rm = T),
            sd = sd(AGE_YEARS),
            min = min(AGE_YEARS),
            max = max(AGE_YEARS)) %>%
  modify(round, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you describe in words what you are trying to accomplish with the `all(duplicated(AGE_YEARS)[-1L])(AGE_YEARS)` portion of your code?

Your error is coming from that portion of your code, where it appears you are trying to multiply an object of logical class (the result of `all(duplicated(AGE_YEARS)[-1L])`) to a (presumably) numeric vector of `AGE_YEARS`.

I'm not sure if that is what you are trying to accomplish, but if you did for whatever reason need to multiply a single logical value to a numeric vector, you would need to include a multiplication sign (*) between the elements.

e.g.

```
all(duplicated(iris$Sepal.Length)[-1L])
# [1] FALSE
all(duplicated(iris$Sepal.Length)[-1L])(iris$Sepal.Length)
# Error: attempt to apply non-function
all(duplicated(iris$Sepal.Length)[-1L])*(iris$Sepal.Length)
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [40] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [79] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [118] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Good luck!

PS in the future it is helpful to include a reproducible example ([How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) of code in your questions!

Comment: Hi! I used the code  "all(duplicated(AGE_YEARS)[-1L])(AGE_YEARS)" because originally it was suggested to us that we use the code "mutate(AGE_YEARS = fct_explicit_na(AGE_YEARS))" however when I entered that it came up with the error   "Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct. Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector." I made "AGE_YEARS" numeric in previous code but for some reason I don't think it has been carried on

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `forcats::fct_explicit_na()`? That function should just be used on factors. It will coerce non-factor variables into factors, so if you want `AGE_YEARS` to be numeric that is not the way to go. 
For all the functions you are using, especially if you aren't familiar with them, I would recommend looking at the documentation and then using them outside the `mutate()` to see what they do, and make sure the result is what you were going for!